# How to get value from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call "handleClick" sending the index of the array like this:

```
{citas.map((cita, i) => (
    <tr className='clickable-row' onClick={handleClick.bind(i)} >
         <td>{cita.CheckIn}</td>
         <td>{cita.CheckOut}</td>
         <td>{cita.Precio}</td>
         <td>{cita.Servicio}</td>
    </tr>
 ))}
```

and this is the handleClick method:

```
const handleClick = (i) => {
    console.log(i)
    history.push("/citasDetalladas/" + ids[i]);
}
```

the problem is that "i" is not what is supposed to be (the array index), as it prints this:
[image]

Comment: just remove the bind `onClick={()=>handleClick(i)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `bind` method is the `this` value. The **second** is the first argument passed to the function:

```
onClick={handleClick.bind(null, i)}
```

You could also create your new function using an arrow function instead:

```
onClick={() => handleClick(i)}
```